# Can't flag answer for "other" reason

Tags: bug, status-norepro

I can't seem to create moderator attention flags when the reason is "other" and which therefore means I need to enter some text.  As far as I can tell, I have checked the right box and entered the text properly:

[image]

Then when I click to submit the flag I get:

[image]

Clearly I entered more than 10 characters as can be seen above.

This has been happening for a while, but I finally now got annoyed enough at it to report the problem.

I am trying to help clean up the site, but it won't let me.

### More information:

I just tried it on a different computer system.  This one is running Win XP and IE 7, and I still have the same problem although it looks a little different:

[image]

And then

[image]

Comment: I hope they can resolve this, but I see a high probability that it is your setup.

Comment: One TS character is more than enough for me, I can't understand that they want 10 of them.

Comment: @Kortuk - Which setup? It's possible that the problem is unique to Olin, but I can't think of any settings in his browser or OS which would cause this. Anyway, no matter what settings may cause it, when you enter 57 characters, and the script complains because there are less than 10, that's what I call a bug.

Comment: @stevenvh, It is a bug, as I said, I hope they resolve, but it could easily be no-repo as using a very old browser can have odd affects.

Comment: The incorrect formatting on the first image and lack of rounded corners on the second image suggest that you are using a really old browser - that's likely the problem. I just tried flagging a Tony answer using the "Other" flag option and it worked fine for me.

Comment: @Simple: WinXP isn't that old, and IE 7 is what came with it.  I can't be the only one running on a WinXP system.

Comment: @Olin: If anything it's the browser, not the OS. After all, XP is (well, [was](http://www.zdnet.com/windows-7-overtakes-xp-mac-os-x-steams-ahead-of-vista-7000003591/) at least last month) more prevalent than Windows 7 (the latest version of Windows) and all other operating systems.

Comment: @Olin - Until this week I also had XP, but now moved to a Win7 machine. On the XP I had to upgrade IE to version 8 for some reason I can't remember, some S/W that didn't work with IE 7. But I use Firefox, so I can't comment on the XP/IE combination. In Firefox never had this problem.

Comment: @OlinLathrop I closed as status no-repo. No one else is having this occur and since it seems tony gave up you are not even having to flag this way anymore! ;)

Answer (score 5):

Internet Explorer 7 is unsupported: [Which browsers are officially supported, and what else do I need?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need/71208#71208)

Stack Exchange provides no guarantees that any feature will work in IE7, and I doubt they'll spend the time to make an IE7-specific fix. Time to upgrade your browser.

[Browse happy](http://browsehappy.com/) :)

**EDIT**

You said you are still running a Windows 2000 machine. [Opera](http://www.opera.com/) supports Windows 2000, so you might want to give that a try.

Comment: Upgrading the browser may sound simple, but one system I am on runs Windows 2000.  Chrome is not available for Win2000, nor any version of IE past 6.

Comment: Give [Opera](http://www.opera.com/) a try: that runs on Windows 2000, and it should support everything you need to run StackExchange sites properly.

Comment: @OlinLathrop I would actually be interested to know if opera fixes it for you.

Answer (score 4):

Olin, you should know better than this ;-)

I have flagged quite a few of Tony's sock puppet accounts using almost the exact wording you show above, and don't have the issue on Vista/Chrome. The "Must be longer than 10 characters" message works correctly.

I seem to recall quite a few instances of problems specific to you because you insist on using   obsolete software. Upgrade your version of windows and browsers to something released in the last 5 years (preferably in the last year) and I think it's likely you will save a lot of time.

Look at it this way - if someone is using a PIC16F84 or a LM741 you wouldn't hesitate to tell them to use something made in this century.

I know it can be a *real* pain to update a networked machine with many years worth of software/work/etc on it, but it gradually causes you more and more problems (and wasted time) not to do so (and makes it more of a big deal when you do)